# Use of unassigned local variable Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

My code is :

```
string text;
int i = 1;
string[] payloadwords;
StreamReader RD = new StreamReader(openfilepay.FileName);
while ((text = RD.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    text = payloadwords[i];
    i++;
}
```

The error I get is :

> Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'payloadwords'

Is there any solution for that problem ?

Comment: What is it today?  This is the third question of this type today?

Comment: Are you trying, `payloadwords[i] = text;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of unassigned local variable 'dictionary'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066792/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-dictionary).  It's about dictionaries but the concept is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other than your problem about assigning variable. (`string[] payloadwords = new string[length];`)

because there are unknown number of elements you cant use array here, you have to use `List<string>` instead.

```
string text;
List<string> payloadwords = new List<string>(); // notice the assigned instance of list
StreamReader RD = new StreamReader(openfilepay.FileName);
while ((text = RD.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    payloadwords.Add(text);
}
```

You dont need counter (`i`) here. you can add a new element to list with `Add` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 1 liner, check out the System.IO.File methods.

```
string[] payloadwords = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openfilepay.FileName);
```